# Selenium using python in mac-I am getting following error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I have set the path in .bashrc as:
PATH="/Users/ddd/Downloads/geckodriver:$PATH"
export PATH

Still I am unable to run simple script can any1 help me...

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "helloselenium.py", line 2, in      driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'\Users\ddd\Downloads\geckodriver.exe')   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 144, in **init**     self.service.start()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start     os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '\Users\ddd\Downloads\geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting geckodriver in ‘/usr/local/bin’

Pass the path,
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path=‘/usr/local/bin/geckodriver’)

Then open terminal type in geckodriver if you see it start,it should also launch Firefox via Selenium

Comment: I am getting this error ..I have set the path to usr/local/bin/geckodriver